# Unable to Inspect elements in Java Website (IE Browser)

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, xpath

I want to verify the installed version of java by navigating to this

URL: https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp in IE browser

When I click on Agree and continue button, it will display the java version.

I want to get the text of the java version displayed to verify it with my value, But I couldn't inspect on the block which displays the java version

I tried looking hmtl,the version value is not available in HTML as well.

Can anyone address this issue?

Comment: Usually the Xpath are common between different browsers. You could try obtain the content with firefox firepath and use on IE. On Safari I find this Xpath `.//span[@id='results_upgrade_block_user_jre']`

Comment: Verify Java version is disabled in Firefox and Chrome as well, tried that already

Comment: I edited my comment

Answer (score 0):

An Image to view the source code and the Xpath:

`.//span[@id='results_upgrade_block_user_jre']`

[image]

In IE11 it seems equals:

[image]

Comment: Tried with the above xpath, Getting No such element exception.
I am using Windows Machine, Can you please check in windows machine?

Comment: Any resolution for this isuue?

Comment: Edited my answer with a IE 11 screenshot.

Comment: Driver.FindElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By.Id("results_upgrade_block_user_jre")).Text;                                               

Tried with the above id, getting NosuchElement exception

Comment: Is there any workaround?   Like any site that doesnt work if java is not present or shows the version of java installed on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

If it have `ID` then try with id

```
driver.findElement(By.id("results_upgrade_block_user_jre"));
```

You can also use xpath like this. also use wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement btn=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'results_upgrade_block_user_jre')]")));
```

Comment: tried with both ID and Xpath, did not work for either

Comment: NoSuchElement Exception

Comment: Is there any workaround? Like any site that doesnt work if java is not present or shows the version of java installed on your PC?